# Emacs can't work with ibus to input chinese

Tags: emacs

My Emacs editor can't work with ibus chinese input method, ibus shows "No input window" when cursor is on Emacs.

I run Emacs with alias like `LC_CTYPE="zh_CN.UTF-8" emacs`, It actually works before, but I have no idea why it doesn't work now, maybe some system update I think.

About my system: Gentoo Linux with Gnome3, I installed Emacs23 and Emacs24, and both of them can't work with ibus now.

PS: Ibus works on other programs, Emacs can display chinese characters well.

Comment: I suggest using ibus-mode http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IBusMode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem only happen on Gentoo. Because system update clear up some fonts. The solution is to install the missing fonts:

`emerge media-fonts/font-adobe-75dpi x11-apps/bdftopcf media-fonts/font-alias media-fonts/font-util`

Then after logout and re-login, I can use input method again.

Comment: I had a similar problem for ibus-1.4.2 in my Funtoo box. I just gave a shot on your method. But, it doesn't work. With which version of ibus do you have this problem?

Comment: @jcadam my environment is ibus-1.4.1 emacs-24.1-r1 Gnome-3.4, if ibus can work on other applications, the problem must be emacs, if install  fonts above can't solve the problem, I have no idea what to do next. If ibus can't work on all applications, the prolem is ibus, you can search for how to enable ibus input method on Linux, there must be many solutions. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem via installing ibus.el and this seems like emacs GTK UI's problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure that ibus is configured correctly by opening the default text editor for your distribution (Mousepad, Leafpad...?), typing control-space and seeing if you can enter Chinese. If you cant you may have to install a Chinese input method or add an input method in the ibus settings.
2. next make sure you have the emacs, ibus mode installed. If you are using a Debian based distribution, the package you want to install will be listed as 'ibus-el'.
3. After installing ibus-el usually control-space will activate and allow you to cycle through your input methods; however, on some of my machines I have to help emacs to get ibus mode started by typing M-x ibus-mode.